# Start a java program, in a new terminal using Runtime.exec

Tags: java

On Linux, what arguments should I pass to `Runtime.exec` so that a new terminal opens and my command executes there?

Comment: Where did Runtime.exec come from?

Comment: gnome-terminal? check this too http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/run-command-in-new-gnome-terminal-185216/

Comment: @Makoto `exec` is a method in class `Runtime`. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...);`